# How to add a button to the end of UIScrollView to load more?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have a scroll with paging. I want to load only 75 pages at a time and when the user reach the last page a button showes up with the last swipe. The button has to be clicked to load more.

The same like ios Zillow app as you see in the attached image.

How should I add this button? Is it part of the scroll or is it just a button out side the scroll?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let's first think about how we initialize our table view. We use

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
```

to return the number of cells we want in the table, so let's say we use something like

```
return searchResultsArray.count
```

but if we want a "Load More Results" button, then let's add 1 more cell

```
return searchResultsArray.count + 1
```

Okay great, now how do we add the button in this new cell? We want to use

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

and we'll say

```
if indexPath.row == searchResultsArray.count
```

(remember that an array's count value is 1 greater than the index of the last element in the array, so this if statement is basically saying, "if this cell is the load more cell")

then we will create our button in this cell, and we can link a function to the button (using a selector) which will add results to the searchResultsArray, and then reload the table (using tableView.reloadData())

This is how you would approach this if it were a (vertical scrolling) table view, but if you want to recreate the horizontal scrolling interface in zillow, then you need to use a collection view, which is a bit complicated if you're new to iOS development, but still use the basic concept I described above. Here's a great video to help you with that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ko9oNhlTwH0

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend you to go for `UICollectionView` rather than `UIScrollView` as with `UIScrollView` you will create multiple objects for your `UIImageView` and ad it in your `UIScrollView` which will take more memory as compare to `UICollectionView`, as with `UICollectionView` you can reuse the same cell so the memory consumed by `UICollectionView` will be very less as compare to `UIScrollView`.

Regrading adding button at the end, create two custom cell in your UICollectionView one is to show UIImageView and one is to show Load More button, fetch 75 results at a time and in the datasource `numberOfItemsInSection` `return` 75+1 (i.e. your array count + 1 [+1 to show load more button when you want to show it])

Now in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` compare if the `indexpath.row` count is greater than your array count then load the cell for Load More button.